# Uploading Video In Summernote

Tags: jquery, summernote

I want to upload video using summernote. I know that, as of now Summernote is allowing  only video link's. Is there any way to achieve upload a video like image upload.

Like binding jquery video uploading plugin with sumernote something like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

summernote does not handle any backend things. And actually, uploaded images are encoded in `base64` and embedded in text itself. This is not suitable for larger images and videos.

I suggest you to make own backend stuff for storing videos. You can use [`jquery-file-upload`](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) or similar plugins to handle large file uploading.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually I did the backend things, and created a link and using the link now I can show the video. Anyway thanks for your time. :)